# Create a manifest file without a .jar file

Tags: java, manifest

I want to store some metadata for one external file in my project, which won't be packed as a .jar. Is there a way to do so?
My guess is that I have to create a Manifest object and then write it out. Can anybody give me some hints?

Comment: You know that a manifest is a simple text file with particular data?

Comment: Yes but I wanted to follow the java Manifest file format and I thought using the class would be the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way, it's something like this:

```
Manifest manifest = new Manifest();
Attributes attr = manifest.getMainAttributes(); 
attr.put(Attributes.Name.MANIFEST_VERSION, "1.0");
// More attributes

FileOutputStream manifestFile = null;
try
{
    manifestFile = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
    manifest.write(manifestFile);
    manifestFile.close();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    log.print(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This command will include only class files

```
jar -cf test.jar *.class
```

If you use maven or other build tool there is a way to configure the maven-build plugin (google maven-build exclude)
Good luck!